# MySQL query for filtering

Tags: mysql

I want to write a query in MySQL for filtering. For example, if there is a column `id` in table `table1` where the filter values for `id` come in a POST request body, saved in variable `A`. I want to extract the matching rows if `A` is not empty and return all rows otherwise. I am not sure about using `IN` with `WHERE`.

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (A)`

One option is that I return all rows from the database and use JavaScript filters, but I don't want to return all rows and expose the entire table to user.

**NOTE: A can be a single value, a tuple or an array.**

Comment: And what's your question about this? Why not try some queries out and see what happens?

Comment: I am here after trying everything I know. Having multiple queries in the script and running some based on JS IF conditions works but I am looking for a more optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use javascript, use `A.join()`, and sanitize your POST.

```
var your_post = [1, 2, 3];

var A = your_post.join();

if (A == '') {
    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM table1';
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    });
} else {
    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (?)';
    con.query(sql, [A], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: I am using nodejs and use ? placeholder for values.

Comment: there is no operator between id and ( ?

Comment: I made an example of how to be used it.

Comment: Please be warned that the given way with `IMPLODE` produces a query that highly vulnerable for SQL injection

Comment: This is why I said to sanitize the POST. He is just learning now I guess.

Comment: I also need the query to return all the rows if the list `A` is empty. And empty string with WHERE clause and IN operator returns 0 rows.

Comment: The answer was updated. I can be done with a simple if statement.